# Flink incremental checkpointing, will Flink automatically remove old checkpoint file?

Tags: apache-flink

For Flink incremental checkpointing, if I understand it correctly, it will first create a full checkpoint, then it will create an incremental checkpoint each time base on the previous one.

Will this chain be super long? Will we need to apply from the very first full checkpoint when restoring?

I've heard that Flink will do compaction/merge periodically, does that mean it will periodically create a full checkpoint so that we don't need to go to the very old full checkpoint during restoring? If so, when will the compaction/merge happen?

And one more question, does Flink save all checkpoint files(including full and incremental)? Or it automatically removes some expired ones?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Background: incremental checkpointing in Flink is currently only supported by the RocksDB state backend, which does most of the heavy lifting. RocksDB is based on log-structured merge trees, which lend themselves naturally to supporting incremental checkpointing.

For an intro to RocksDB, see https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/RocksDB-Basics.

Now for your questions:

The chain is bounded in length by the number of levels used in RocksDB. Since the size of each level is generally some multiple of the size of the previous level, it doesn't take a very long chain to store a lot of data. The "original checkpoint" isn't a monolith -- it comprises state held in multiple levels of the LSM tree, and stored in a set of SST files -- and once compaction begins, the original checkpoint no longer exists in any recognizable way.

The compaction is simply part of how RocksDB works; it's not something implemented by or for Flink. Compaction is occurring more or less continuously in the background.

Flink does take care to automatically delete SST files (a checkpoint comprises a set of SST files) that are no longer useful.

See [Managing Large State in Apache Flink: An Intro to Incremental Checkpointing](https://flink.apache.org/features/2018/01/30/incremental-checkpointing.html) for more.